# Issues with objects, enumerated types, scope

Tags: c++, class, object, enums

I feel like I am running in circles trying to pinpoint why compiler errors are happening. I am going to give the (long) list of compiler errors I am getting, and hope that somebody may have a recommendation on how to remedy these errors. I am including 4 files, one of which is very long, but for the sake of completeness, I will provide the whole thing.

Any help with any small bit of errors would be so much appreciated.

List of compiler errors:

```
world.cpp:13:1: error: ‘World’ does not name a type
 World::World(string explorer)
 ^
world.cpp:28:6: error: ‘World’ has not been declared
 void World::setNumPits(int pits)
  ^
world.cpp: In function ‘void setNumPits(int)’:
world.cpp:30:9: error: ‘numPits’ was not declared in this scope
     numPits = pits;
     ^
world.cpp: At global scope:
world.cpp:37:5: error: ‘World’ has not been declared
int World::getNumPits()
 ^
world.cpp: In function ‘int getNumPits()’:
world.cpp:39:9: error: ‘numPits’ was not declared in this scope
  return numPits;
     ^
world.cpp: At global scope:
world.cpp:46:6: error: ‘World’ has not been declared
 void World::setType()
  ^
world.cpp: In function ‘void setType()’:
world.cpp:50:2: error: ‘board’ was not declared in this scope
   board[0][4].setType(type);  // The explorer will always begin at this position
  ^
  world.cpp:80:23: error: ‘numPits’ was not declared in this scope
   for (int i = 0; i <= numPits; i++) 
                   ^
 world.cpp: In function ‘void setFace(Facing)’:
 world.cpp:108:7: error: ‘board’ was not declared in this scope
    if (board[i][j].getType() == YOU)
       ^
world.cpp: In function ‘void setBreeze(bool)’:
world.cpp:132:25: error: ‘board’ was not declared in this scope
                 if (board[i + 1][j].getType() == PIT)
                     ^
world.cpp:151:25: error: ‘board’ was not declared in this scope
                 if (board[i + 1][j].getType() == PIT)
                     ^
world.cpp:171:25: error: ‘board’ was not declared in this scope
                 if (board[i][j + 1].getType() == PIT)
                     ^
world.cpp:205:6: error: ‘World’ has not been declared
void World::setStench()
  ^
world.cpp:206:1: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
world.cpp:1600:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
 }
 ^
world.cpp:1600:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
world.cpp: In function ‘int getNumPits()’:
world.cpp:40:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
gameobject.cpp:9:1: error: ‘GameObject’ does not name a type
GameObject::GameObject()
 ^
gameobject.cpp:19:6: error: ‘GameObject’ has not been declared
 void GameObject::setFace(Facing direct)
      ^
gameobject.cpp:19:26: error: variable or field ‘setFace’ declared void
 void GameObject::setFace(Facing direct)
                          ^
gameobject.cpp:19:26: error: ‘Facing’ was not declared in this scope
gameobject.cpp:28:6: error: ‘GameObject’ has not been declared
 void GameObject::setType(Type square)
      ^
gameobject.cpp:28:26: error: variable or field ‘setType’ declared void
void GameObject::setType(Type square)
                          ^
gameobject.cpp:28:26: error: ‘Type’ was not declared in this scope
gameobject.cpp:38:1: error: ‘Facing’ does not name a type
Facing GameObject::getFace()
^
gameobject.cpp:47:1: error: ‘Type’ does not name a type
Type GameObject::getType()
 ^
gameobject.cpp:56:6: error: ‘GameObject’ has not been declared
void GameObject::setBreeze(bool pitAdj)
      ^
gameobject.cpp: In function ‘void setBreeze(bool)’:
gameobject.cpp:58:2: error: ‘breeze’ was not declared in this scope
  breeze = pitAdj;
  ^
gameobject.cpp: At global scope:
gameobject.cpp:65:6: error: ‘GameObject’ has not been declared
void GameObject::setStench(bool wumpAdj)
     ^
gameobject.cpp: In function ‘void setStench(bool)’:
gameobject.cpp:67:2: error: ‘stench’ was not declared in this scope
 stench = wumpAdj;
  ^
gameobject.cpp: At global scope:
 gameobject.cpp:74:6: error: ‘GameObject’ has not been declared
 bool GameObject::getBreeze()
      ^
 gameobject.cpp: In function ‘bool getBreeze()’:
gameobject.cpp:76:9: error: ‘breeze’ was not declared in this scope
    return breeze;
     ^
 gameobject.cpp: At global scope:
 gameobject.cpp:83:6: error: ‘GameObject’ has not been declared
  bool GameObject::getStench()
       ^
gameobject.cpp: In function ‘bool getStench()’:
gameobject.cpp:85:9: error: ‘stench’ was not declared in this scope
 return stench;
     ^
gameobject.cpp: In function ‘bool getBreeze()’:
gameobject.cpp:77:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
gameobject.cpp: In function ‘bool getStench()’:
gameobject.cpp:86:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
```

And this is my gameobject.h file which has my class definition for GameObject

```
// Specification file for the GameObject class
#ifndef GAMEOBJECT_H
#define GAMEOBJECT_H
using namespace std;
// GameObject class declaration

class GameObject
{
    private:
        Type type;
        Facing face;
        bool stench;
        bool breeze;
    public:
        GameObject();   // Constructor  
        void setFace(Facing);
        void setType(Type);
        void setBreeze(bool);
        void setStench(bool);
        Facing getFace();
        Type getType();
        bool getBreeze();
        bool getStench();
};

#endif
```

This is my gameObject.cpp,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//************************************************************
// Constructor for GameObject                    *              
//************************************************************

GameObject::GameObject()
{
    type = BLANK;
    face = EAST;
}

//************************************************************
// setFace sets the value of the member variable face        *
//************************************************************

void GameObject::setFace(Facing direct)
{
    face = direct;
}

//************************************************************
// setType sets the value of the member variable type        *
//************************************************************

void GameObject::setType(Type square)
{
    type = square;
}


//************************************************************
// getFace sets the value of the member variable face        *
//************************************************************

Facing GameObject::getFace()
{
    return face;
}

//************************************************************
// getType sets the value of the member variable type        *
//************************************************************

Type GameObject::getType()
{
    return type;
}

//************************************************************
// setBreeze sets the value of the member variable breeze    *
//************************************************************

void GameObject::setBreeze(bool pitAdj)
{
    breeze = pitAdj;
}

//************************************************************
// setStench sets the value of the member variable stench    *
//************************************************************

void GameObject::setStench(bool wumpAdj)
{
    stench = wumpAdj;
}

//************************************************************
// getBreeze returns the value of the member variable breeze *
//************************************************************

bool GameObject::getBreeze()
{
    return breeze;
}

//************************************************************
// getStench returns the value of the member variable stench  *
//************************************************************

bool GameObject::getStench()
{
    return stench;
}
```

this is my world.h file which defines the World class

```
    //Specification file for the World Class
    #ifndef WORLD_H
    #define WORLD_H
    #include "gameobject.h"
    using namespace std;

    enum Type { YOU, WUMPUS, GOLD, PIT, BLANK }; // Enumerated types of objects
    enum Facing { NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST };   // Enumerated directions

    //World class declaration

    class World
    {
        private:
            GameObject board[4][4];     //Array of GameObjects
            string name;
            int numPits;
            bool breeze;
            bool stench;
            Facing temp;

         public:
            World(string);              //Constructor
            void setNumPits(int);
            int getNumPits();
            void setType();
            void setFace(Facing);
            void setBreeze();
            void setStench();
            void setBoard();
            void displayBoard();
            void displayOptions(int);
            void changeDirections();
            void move();
            void wumpusDeath();
            void pitDeath();
            void shoot();
            void wumpusKilled();
            void getGold();
            void quitGame();
    };

    #endif
```

I can't include my entire world.cpp, but here is the beggining of it, and I tried to include all code that gave a compiler error.

```
    //Implementation file for World class
#include "gameobject.h"     //For the GameObject class
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//************************************************************
// Constructor for World                                     *
//************************************************************

World::World(string explorer)
{
    explorer = name;

    // Get the system time
    unsigned seed = time(0);

    // Seed the random number generator
    srand(seed);
}

//************************************************************
// setNumPits sets the vslue of the memeber variable numPits *
//************************************************************

void World::setNumPits(int pits)
{
        numPits = pits;
}

//************************************************************
// getNumPits returns the value of the variable numPits      *
//************************************************************

int World::getNumPits()
{
    return numPits;
}

//************************************************************
// setType sets the member variable type in GameObject array *
//************************************************************

void World::setType()
{
    Type type;
    type = YOU;
    board[0][4].setType(type);  // The explorer will always begin at this position

    // Randomly selects location of WUMPUS
    int wRows, wCols;
    wRows = rand() % 4;
        wCols = rand() % 4;
    // If square is takem, generates random values until a blank is found
    while (board[wRows][wCols].getType() != BLANK)
    {
            wRows = rand() % 4;
            wCols = rand() % 4;
    }
    type = WUMPUS;
    board[wRows][wCols].setType(type);  // Places the WUMPUS

    // Randomly selects location of GOLD
    int gRows, gCols;
        gRows = rand() % 4;
        gCols = rand() % 4;
    // If square is taken, generates random values until a blank is found
        while (board[gRows][gCols].getType() != BLANK)
        {
            gRows = rand() % 4;
            gCols = rand() % 4;
    }
    type = GOLD;
    board[gRows][gCols].setType(type);  // Places the GOLD

    // Randomly selects location of PITS
    int pRows, pCols;
    for (int i = 0; i <= numPits; i++)  // Places the number of PITS randomly selected
    {
        pRows = rand() % 4;
        pCols = rand() % 4;
            // If square is taken, generates random values until a blank is found
        while (board[pRows][pCols].getType() != BLANK)
        {
            pRows = rand() % 4;
            pCols = rand() % 4;
        }
        type = PIT;
        board[pRows][pCols].setType(type);  // Places the PIT
    }

    // All other types remain BLANK
}       

//************************************************************
// setFace sets the direction YOU is facing                  *
//************************************************************

void setFace(Facing direction)
{
    Facing face;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
        if (board[i][j].getType() == YOU)
        {
            face = direction;
            board[i][j].setFace(face);
        }
        }
    }
}

//************************************************************
// setBreeze sets the attribute breeze                       *
//************************************************************

void setBreeze(bool breeze)
{
    bool breeze = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
        // Tests corner squares for attributes
                if (j == 4)
                {  
            // Tests for breeze
                    if (board[i + 1][j].getType() == PIT)
                    {
                    breeze = true;
                        board[i + 1][j].getBreeze(breeze);
                    }
                    else if (board[i][j - 1].getType() == PIT)
                    {
                        breeze = true;
                        board[i][j - 1].getBreeze(breeze);
                    }
                    else if (board[i + 1][j - 1].getType() == PIT)
                    {
                        breeze = true;
                        board[i + 1][j - 1].getBreeze(breeze);
                    }
                }  
            if (j == 0)
                {
            // Tests for breeze
                    if (board[i + 1][j].getType() == PIT)
                    {
                        breeze = true;
                        board[i + 1][j].getBreeze(breeze);
                    }
                    else if (board[i][j + 1].getType() == PIT)
                    {
                        breeze = true;
                        board[i][j + 1].getBreeze(breeze);
                    }
                    else if (board[i + 1][j + 1].getType() == PIT)
                    {
                        breeze = true;
                        board[i + 1][j + 1].getBreeze(breeze);
                    }
                {
            // Tests top row for attributes
                if (j > 0 && j < 4)
                {
            // Tests for breeze
                    if (board[i][j + 1].getType() == PIT)
                    {
                        breeze = true;
                        board[i][j + 1].getBreeze(breeze);
                    }   
                    else if (board[i][j - 1].getType() == PIT)
                    {
                        breeze = true;
                        board[i][j - 1].getBreeze(breeze);
                    } 
                    else if (board[i + 1][j].getType() == PIT)
                    {
                        breeze = true;
                        board[i + 1][j].getBreeze(breeze);
                    }
                    else if (board[i + 1][j + 1].getType() == PIT)
                    {
                        breeze = true;
                        board[i + 1][j + 1].getBreeze(breeze);
                    }
                    else if (board[i + 1][j - 1].getType() == PIT)
                    {
                        breeze = true;
                        board[i + 1][j - 1].getBreeze(breeze);
                    }
             }
        }
    }
}

//************************************************************
// setStench displays the game board                      *
//************************************************************

void World::setStench()
{
    bool stench = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
        // Tests corner squares for attributes
                if (i == 0 && j == 4)
                {  
            // Tests for breeze
                    if (board[i + 1][j].getType() == WUMPUS)
                    {
                    stench = true;
                        board[i + 1][j].getStench(stench);
                    }
                    else if (board[i][j - 1].getType() == WUMPUS)
                    {
                        stench = true;
                        board[i][j - 1].getStench(stench);
                    }
                    else if (board[i + 1][j - 1].getType() == WUMPUS)
                    {
                        stench = true;
                        board[i + 1][j - 1].getStench(stench);
                    }
                }  
            if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                {
            // Tests for breeze
                    if (board[i + 1][j].getType() == WUMPUS)
                    {
                        stench = true;
                        board[i + 1][j].getStench(stench);
                    }
                    else if (board[i][j + 1].getType() == WUMPUS)
                    {
                        stench = true;
                        board[i][j + 1].getStench(stench);
                    }
                    else if (board[i + 1][j + 1].getType() == WUMPUS)
                    {
                        stench = true;
                        board[i + 1][j + 1].getStench(stench);
                    }
                {
            // Tests top row for attributes
                if (i == 0 && j > 0 && j < 4)
                {
            // Tests for breeze
                    if (board[i][j + 1].getType() == WUMPUS)
                    {
                        stench = true;
                        board[i][j + 1].getStench(stench);
                    }   
                    else if (board[i][j - 1].getType() == WUMPUS)
                    {
                        stench = true;
                        board[i][j - 1].getStench(stench);
                    } 
                    else if (board[i + 1][j].getType() == WUMPUS)
                    {
                        stench = true;
                        board[i + 1][j].getStench(stench);
                    }
                    else if (board[i + 1][j + 1].getType() == WUMPUS)
                    {
                        stench = true;
                        board[i + 1][j + 1].getStench(stench);
                    }
                    else if (board[i + 1][j - 1].getType() == WUMPUS)
                    {
                        stench = true;
                        board[i + 1][j - 1].getStench(stench);
                    }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, World.cpp should `#include world.h`.  That might solve a lot of your problems at once.  Generally, when you're getting a lot of errors, they might be solved by fixing one or two basic problems.

Comment: `#include "world.h"` in implementation

Comment: Wait, did you write all this code at once, without trying to compile any of it, and only NOW you're trying to compile all of this? That's completely the wrong approach. The right way to do it: write a little bit of code, compile it, test it, make sure it works, then write some more code, and repeat.

Comment: Please review what a [mcve] is. That is the form of questions we are looking for. It will also help you track down your problem. Keep removing things until you find the smallest unit that can still reproduce your error... then see if you can figure out what the error is from that small unit.

Comment: @TingRay This isn't a do-your-homework-on-demand service.

Comment: @Barry but it is a resource for issues in code. The problems I had were obviously silly, but because I am novice, I could not easily identify them. After reaching out to my professor and fellow classmates to no avail, and out of DESPERATION I posted a maximal example because I didn't know where the issues were located within my code. If I knew more, or could focus in on one section of code, I would have. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the errors you are getting are related:

- `'...' has not been declared`
- `'...' does not name a type`
- `'...' was not declared in this scope`

They mean that the compiler can't find the declarations for those objects, because they are in separate files and you are not including them where needed.

---

For example, in `gameObject.cpp`, you are declaring the functions of the `GameObject` class, but you are not including `gameobject.h`, so the compiler can't find that class, which results in an error.

Comment: In addition to that, at some point the OP for some unexplainable reason suddenly stops including class name into apparent member definitions, e.g. `void setFace(Facing direction)` instead of `void World::setFace(Facing direction)`.